# When I store a bytearray with more than 100,000 index into the sqlite, I can only get 20 index of it while I select it from the table

Tags: android, sqlite

Here's what happen: 
When I convert a bitmap into a bytearray, the bytearray stores more than 100,000 index, but when I use the `SELECT` function to get the bytearray, the bytearray have only 20 index left. What happen?

My field is using `BLOB` to store the bytearray, and the following code is what I'm trying to get the bytearray:

```
private void insertAttachmentRecord(int parentid) {

    for(int k = 0; k < attachmentarray.size(); k++) {
        byte[] claimAttachmentByteArray;
        newAttachmentRecord = new ContentValues();
        claimAttachmentByteArray = attachmentarray.get(k).getImageByteArray();
        newAttachmentRecord.put("claimattachmentimage", claimAttachmentByteArray);
        newAttachmentRecord.put("parent_id", parentid);
        claiminfoDB.insert(DBATTACHMENT_TABLE, null, newAttachmentRecord);
    }
}
```

And the query to get the bytearray:

```
private ArrayList<ClaimViewResult> GetClaimViewResult() {
    ArrayList<ClaimViewResult> results = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor c2 = claiminfoDB.rawQuery("SELECT 'claimattachmentimage' FROM 'claimattachment' WHERE parent_id = "+bundletableId, null);

    if (c2.getCount() != 0) {
        c2.moveToFirst();

        ClaimViewResult cvr = new ClaimViewResult();
        byte[] imagebytearray = c2.getBlob(0);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagebytearray, 0, imagebytearray.length);
        cvr.setBitmap(bitmap);
        cvr.setFilename(getFilename());
        results.add(cvr);
        while (c2.moveToNext()) {
            cvr = new ClaimViewResult();
            imagebytearray = c2.getBlob(0);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagebytearray, 0, imagebytearray.length);
            cvr.setBitmap(bitmap);
            cvr.setFilename(getFilename());

            results.add(cvr);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you need to change scheme for saving your bitmaps? For example, you can store bitmaps in inner app's directory and saving path to this image in database.

Also, you can try to change your `select` query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table;
```

I think, you can receive only 20 bytes because you select **word**, not a column (I mean 'claimattachmentimage' in your query)

Comment: So is that mean my bytearray is too big to store in the sqlite?

Comment: No, it isn't a problem. AIK, SQLite has no limits for that. I just think, that it is bad practice to store bitmaps in database.

Comment: SELECT * works, thanks a lot, you just saved my day!